# MVC4 C# Populating data in a viewmodel from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel which needs data from two models person and address:

Models:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public int Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public int Zip { get; set; }
   public int PersonId {get; set; }
}
```

The Viewmodel is as such

```
public class PersonAddViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried several ways to get data into the viewmodel and pass it to the view.  There will be multiple records returned to display.

My latest method is populating the view model as such:

```
private AppContexts db = new AppContexts();
public ActionResult ListPeople()
{
    var model = new PersonAddViewModel();
    var people = db.Persons;
    foreach(Person p in people)
    {
        Address address = db.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(a => a.PersonId == p.Id)
        model.Id = p.Id;
        model.Name = p.Name;
        model.Street = address.Street;
    }
    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

I get an error on the Address address = db... line of "EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code.

How can you populate a view model with multiple records and pass to a view?

Final Solution:

```
private AppContexts db = new AppContexts();
private AppContexts dbt = new AppContexts();
public ActionResult ListPeople()
{
    List<PersonAddViewModel> list = new List<PersonAddViewModel>();
    var people = db.Persons;
    foreach(Person p in people)
    {
        PersonAddViewModel model = new PersonAddViewModel();
        Address address = dbt.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(a => a.PersonId == p.Id)
        model.Id = p.Id;
        model.Name = p.Name;
        model.Street = address.Street;
    }
    return View(list);
}
```

Comment: What is `db` in this case? And what is the message of the exception?  Are you using Entity Framework or LinqToSql?  Whatever `db` is seems to be having trouble executing the command to retrieve the data but without more info, it could be anything.

Comment: @Brian S I am using entity framework.  db is the context.

Comment: Why are you not using navigation properties?

Comment: @sylon I am not exactly sure what you mean by navigation properties?  I looked it up and found it would be something like this in my case public virtual Person Person in my Address model?

Comment: @Xaxum give us the details of the exception?

Comment: @sylon Looked into the error in more detail and it was this.  there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first.  So it was complaining about iterating over the open context.  I added a second context and got rid of the error but then had another error.  Posting solution above.

Comment: Yes, "there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first" is the problem, for those thinking it had to do with anything other than that.  It is looking at 2 connections/table reads at the same time, asynchronously, because of adding a property of one table (Addresses) while iterating through another (Person).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, EntityCommandExecutionException errors indicates an error in the definition of your entity context, or the entities themselves.  This is throwing an exception because it's found the database to be different from the way you told it that it should be.  You need to figure out that problem.

Second, regarding the proper way to do this, the code you've shown should work if your context were correctly configured.  But, a better way would be to use Navigational properties, so long as you want to get all related records and not specify other Where clause parameters.  A navigational property might look like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public int Gender { get; set; }

   public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
   // or possibly, if you want more than one address per person
   public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public int Zip { get; set; }
   public int PersonId { get; set; }

   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would simply say:

```
public ActionResult ListPeople()
{
    var model = (from p in db.Persons // .Includes("Addresses") here?
                select new PersonAddViewModel() {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Street = p.Address.Street,
                    // or if collection
                    Street2 = p.Addresses.Select(a => a.Street).FirstOrDefault()
                });

    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Note: If setting this up to use a collection, using `.FirstOrDefault()` will give you only the first address in the collection - even though all of them will be in the collection. But since the OP's code had `.SingleOrDefault()`, I suppose this was already accounted for. `.FirstOrDefault()` is also better than `.SingleOrDefault()`, since "single" is more for when you know you will only get one response.

Comment: Sorry one more note: To get this to work for me, I had to add `.Include("Addresses")` at the end of `db.Persons` before the collection would fill in.  I edited the post to include a comment on this and correction of many syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying lists of objects, you could use a generic view model that has a generic list:

```
public class GenericViewModel<T>
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }

    public GenericViewModel()
    {
        this.Results = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Have a controller action that returns, say all people from your database:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAllPeople(GenericViewModel<People> viewModel)
{
    var query = (from x in db.People select x); // Select all people
    viewModel.Results = query.ToList();

    return View("_MyView", viewModel);
}
```

Then make your view strongly typed, taking in your generic view model:

```
@model NameSpace.ViewModels.GenericViewModel<NameSpace.Models.People>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not sure how this would get the data from the address model data as well?  I can get the people or the address without an issue it is just when I try to use a viewmodel to combine them into one model the issue aries.

Comment: You should create a relationship between Person and Address, it'll depend on the scope of your app, but for simplicity let's say it's a 1:1 i.e. one Person has one Address. Then you'll be able to access a person's address like person.Address.City etc. in your view. Here's a link on to Code First associations http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Comment: Is this what @sylon was mentioning above as navigation properties?  I have a one to many relationship, one person can have many addresses.  The foreign keys were set up by entity framework but maybe without the virtual I can't reference like person.Adddress.City.

Comment: Yes you need to specify the navigation properties as described in @sylons answer.

Comment: Thanks for the option.  This helped get to where I had to be.