# Populating ViewModel from EntityModel and Vice Versa in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have started working with MVC for sometime now and I am learning different approached to different scenarios. There can be different ways of handling a single scenario and it can be quite debatable that which one is more effective and better then other.

My confusion is related to the use of Entity models and View Models. I have created separate entity models for every database entity and also create separate view models for every view. Now I have a simple view with textboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes and dropdown lists on it. I have two way databinding on the view and I use the same view for creating new records and editing existing records.

My confusion is that I am retrieving the entity model from the database and populating each field of ViewModel from the entity model and then passing the ViewMoel to the model. Now this has to be done manually for each field. So is there some way through which the ViewModel adn Entity Models are auto mapped on the runtime? For example, on one simple view I am doing the following,

```
List<User> UserList = db.Users.ToList();

        List<UserViewModel> UsersViewModel = new List<UserViewModel>();
        foreach (User user in UserList)
        {
            UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
            model.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            model.LastName = user.LastName;
            model.DOB = user.DOB;
            model.Addresses = user.Addresses;
        }
```

When the ViewModel is populated manually I pass it to the view. Also for saving the records to the database I do the opposite and populates the Entity model from ViewModel. To me there must be some more effective and shorter way of doing what I am doing. I have checked a similar question here at [MVC4 C# Populating data in a viewmodel from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071531/mvc4-c-sharp-populating-data-in-a-viewmodel-from-database) but it is not answering my question and rather addressing some error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). Once you configure the mappings you can populate your view models like so:

```
var user = db.Users.First();
var uservm = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(user);

var users = db.Users.ToList();
var usersvm = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserViewModel>>(users);
```

Generally, the auto mapping is one-way and safe only for Entity to View Model. Mapping back to the Entity type is still manually done.

As for your manual example, for performance reasons, you want to use a projection instead of iterating:

```
var users = db.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel {
    FirstName = u.FirstName,
    LastName = u.LastName,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I was already looking into the AutoMapper and finding whether it works two ways or not. I understand what you have mentioned. I still have one confusion. If I have an IEnumerable field in the Entity model then how can I have the same field in the ViewModel. I am confused because if User entity has IEnumerable<Addresses> in it then should I use the same IEnumerable<Addresses> as some folks on internet are using List or SelectList. If that is the case then how will be mapping done. Also the mapping will be on runtime or can I use some Annotations too?

Comment: My view models don't ever contain Entity properties. So a `UserViewModel` would contain a collection of `AddressViewModels`. Once you configure the mapping for the `Address`, composite view model types should automatically use the Address mapping. Actually, I map most of my entities to [DTOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) and my service classes never expose the entity types to my controllers or views.